# What does one need besides the approval of fellow scholars, to be called a scholar?

Tags: islamic-scholar

I don't currently intend to become one  (I don't really have the time right now). I was wondering this in order to know the kind of background people called scholars have. One can always look their individual background in biographies  (if one is available). Is there a condition common to all schools and countries ?

Comment: I recommend you to narrow this question as it is too broad. Maybe by asking about giving fatwa...

Comment: There are many conditions until i'll have time to write an answer I recommend you to read on wikipedia the article on in ijtihad as there are some basical similarities.

Comment: I assume you can read Arabic here's a Biography of a scholar quoting his background http://www.dedewnet.com/index.php/about-us/2010-07-03-07-50-14.html

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones the answers of the duplicate are poor!