# can I call this people atheist?

Tags: kufr, atheists

If someone uttered words of disbelief or mocked Islam or disbelieved in pillers of faith or disbelieved in Allah and his attributes and powers can I call him a Kafir/disbeliever/atheist?

Answer (score 1):

If they actually have willingly done what you claim then it is permissible to call them kafir/disbeliever as they have committed Kufr and the word falls true on them. It would be in the first case mentioned in the hadith:

> أيما امرئ قال لأخيه: يا كافر، فقد باء بها أحدهما، إن كان كما قال، وإلا رجعت عليه
>
> Any man who says to his brother: "O disbeliever," it will apply to one of them.
> **Either it is as he said**, otherwise it will come back to him.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/122)</sup>

Uttering words of disbelief or mocking does nullify Islam, even if done in jest:

> قل أبالله وآياته ورسوله كنتم تستهزئون لا تعتذروا قد كفرتم بعد إيمانكم
>
> Say, "Is it Allah and His verses and His Messenger that you were mocking?" Make no excuse; you have disbelieved after your belief.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:65-66](http://legacy.quran.com/9/65-66)</sup>

Comment: The person said"........ like Allah is dead" naujubillah. Can i call this person atheist because the person disbelieved Allah's power?

Comment: Yes it could be if he said that intentionally, as that is an insult and denial of Allah.  No if it was a slip of the tongue or if the complete sentence had some context which meant something else.

Comment: It was intentional because it was posted in Facebook and the full post was about insult of Islam.

Comment: I didn't call one kafir in front of the person. Do i have any sin?

Comment: I have already answered, if he did commit Kufr then there is no sin in calling him Kafir.

Answer (score -3):

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

You are not allowed to call someone kafir because only Allah knows the people that believe and the people that disbelieve. Also by calling someone a kafir can also make you too as a kafir, there is an Hadith that one said

Sahih al-Bukhari 6103
Narrated Abu Huraira:

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "If a man says to his brother, O Kafir (disbeliever)!' Then surely one of them is such (i.e., a Kafir). "

So please my brother don't call someone a kafir

Wasalamu alaikum

Comment: That does not apply when someone actually has committed Kufr. See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46856/

Comment: What if one did not say it directly in front of one or publicly?